# dispatch ListView item action

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview which has an image, text...I have implement setOnItemClickListener method on the listview to excute an action but  I also want to add a star icon in order to save it in my favorite on the listView Display.
How can I do that ? should I use a Two line display ? or subdivise my list view ?

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple

Just click on list and set image on list and its image property set gone

and after click on list item then display image (set property visible). And store this position.

Answer (score 0):

In your listAdapter class constructor, you should add a boolean parameter which describes items favourite or not. And in listAdapter class getView method, you can use a snippet as follow:

```
if (isFavourite) {
            ImageView imgFavourite = (ImageView) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgFavourite);
            imgFavourite.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_favourite));
        }
```